# Parsing Json Date object with Spring Controller yields JsonSyntaxException works properly for some objects but not in nested objects

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am encountering the following exception in the Spring controller:

```
WARN  o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Mar 24, 2017; nested exception is com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: Mar 24, 2017
```

The model I am using:

```
public class ProductCommons {
    private Integer id;
    ...
    private Date createdAt;
    private Date deletedAt;
    //getters and setters here
}
```

I am trying to post a Cart Object as json, the same (but modified) object I get when I do a GET request on that cart object. Now, **Cart** Object has a nested list of **CartItem** (yes, another model). Each CartItem consist of a **Product** (another model -_-), and each Product consist of (finally,) **ProductCommons** object.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "someval", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    public Cart add(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody Cart cart, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return new Cart();
        }
        // application logic here
    }
```

When I send a post request, I get a **400** response, with the message: 
**The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.**

But if I **erase the createdAt field from the ProductCommons json portion**, I can successfully receive the data. Please note, I can also receive the data that has been sent in the cartItem objects as well as the cart object.
Although the createdAt date is not completely necessary to perform the add operation here, I feel I should learn why the same formatted date is failed to be parsed in ProductCommons object but is parsed in Cart and CartItem objects, when the single request contains all of them?

Also, please note that I am not using gson here to parse any json.

The structure of my json is (and I have validated it a thousand times):

```
{
    id: 1,
    ...,
    createdAt: "Mar 17, 2017",
    cartItems: [{
        id: 1,
        ...,
        product: {
            id: 1,
            ...,
            productCommons: {
                id: 1,
                ...,
                createdAt: "Mar 17, 2017"
            }
        },
        createdAt: "Mar 16, 2017"

    }]
}
```

Comment: serialize your javascript object with JSON.stringify and try.

Comment: Here's the catch, I'm not using js. I'm using postman to send these data. @surya

Comment: Ok can you use some plugin to format Json ( e.g..Json plugin in notepad++) and try

Comment: I tried formatting the results in postman and also from  various other Json Formatter and validator, to no avail!

Comment: It sounds as if dates in nested objects are causing problems..you can debug with gson in a java main class from that string ..may be you need Json serializer/deserializer

Comment: it's definitely the dates nested inside. I need to read up on json serialization and deserialization though. However, what confuses me is that the date object in the 4th layer is getting caught but upto the 3rd seems fine. why?

Comment: It sounds weird, it's hard to believe it can work for the outer nodes because Gson cannot parse such date format by default. Did you manage to resolve the issue? What does happen if you remove the product commons?

Comment: `private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, (JsonDeserializer<Date>) (jsonElement, type, context) -> { try { return new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy", US).parse(jsonElement.getAsString()); } catch ( final ParseException ex ) { throw new JsonParseException(ex); } }).create();` -- maybe it'll be helpful for you.